# How to edit own kwargs from inside a function?

Tags: python

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def f(a):
    print(f"{locals()}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f(1)
```

Output: `{'a': 1}`

Want to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def f(a):
    kwargs["b"] = 2
    print(f"{locals()}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f(1)
```

to get the output `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

What's the right syntax for that?

Comment: if you do just `b = 2`, then you will get that output

Comment: Perhaps you can use the function signature `f(**kwargs)` and then you can access and modify kwargs.

Comment: Related to keyword arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? For example, are you trying to add keyword arguments to pass on to another function?

Comment: @SolomonUcko some code gets a variable from the context, I'm trying to detangle what part of it gets that variable. I thought it does this by calling `locals()`, but if just `b = 2` solves that then it's some other part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your `kwargs` dict before trying to index it:

```
def f(a):
    kwargs = locals()
    kwargs["b"] = 2
    print(kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's just `b = 2`.

My actual problem was on the outside with one of the decorators that wanted the function to have one specific argument. Can't do much about that.